# Proof for a solution set involving optimization

Tags: optimization, 3d

> $$f(x,y) = 2x + y$$
> $$g(x,y) = x * y$$
> Prove that for all/any $f(x,y)$ (constraints: $x > 0$ and $y > 0$), $g(x,y)$ is maximized (optimized?) when $y = 2x$.

The highest level mathematics course I have taken is Calculus 3 in university, but I forgot a good amount. The explanation doesn't have to be super formal/in-depth. Thanks! This just piqued my interest because the functions come from a video game.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to prove. How is $f(x,y)$ related to $g(x,y)$? Do you mean for any constant $c$ such that $f(x,y)=c$...?

Comment: Uh I'm not sure how they're related, if at all, they just take the same inputs, just different functions. And yes, thank you for clarifying: for any constant c such that f(x,y) = c. For any c, we have a set of solutions, namely 2x + y = c. Out of these infinitely many solutions, I want to pick the (x,y) such that g(x,y) is maximized. I want to know why y = 2x is the optimal solution. For example, if c = 2, then the solution (0.5, 1) maximizes g(x,y). I'm just not sure why, or how to generalize it to any c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrei pointed out, it's not very clear what you are trying to prove here. If the restriction is only $x,y>0$, then $g$ doesn't have any maximum, since the bigger $x,y$, the bigger $x\cdot{y}$ gets. If you add the restriction that $2x+y=c$ for some constant $c$, then $g(x,y)=g(x,c-2x)=cx-2x^2$ which is a parabola with the maximum at $x=\frac{c}{4}$. So, $y=c-\frac{2c}{4}=\frac{c}{2}$. That is, $(\frac{c}{4},\frac{c}{2})$ maximizes $g$ on the set $\{(x,y):2x+y=c\}$.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Sorry, like I said I'm not too well-versed in math so I didn't know how to phrase my question/problem properly. That restriction 2x + y = c is what I needed.